# Typescript: how to set type of children in React Component?

Tags: typescript, reactjs

Can i set type of children in TypeScript?

For example i have such Components

```
class UserProfile extends React.Component<{ id: number }, void>{
}

class Thumbnail extends React.Component<{ children: UserProfile[] }, void>{

}

class UsersList extends React.Component<void, void>{

    public render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Thumbnail><UserProfile id={1} /></Thumbnail>
                <Thumbnail><UserProfile id={2} /></Thumbnail>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I want to define what particular children are supported in Thumbnail component in order to avoid such situation:

```
class UsersList extends React.Component<void, void>{

    public render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Thumbnail><UserProfile id={1} /></Thumbnail>
                <Thumbnail><UserProfile id={2} /></Thumbnail>
                <Thumbnail><span>Some plain text</span></Thumbnail> // This should be forbidden because Thumbnail component expects to have an array of UserProfile elements as it can handle them
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This example doesn't work, but is there any way to do it?

Comment: I've looked for a way to do this and I don't think you can. The JSX outputs Elements, not your component class types. What you can do is inspect the `children` in your render function and check the `type`, and throw an error if its not what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> set type of children in React Component?

Can't be narrowed with a type annotation (its all JSX.Element). Can be done with runtime introspection (`type` property of each child).

Comment: I found this way, but it looks weird:

`
    private static propTypes = {
        children: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
            React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.shape({ type: React.PropTypes.oneOf([Cell]) })),
            React.PropTypes.shape({ type: React.PropTypes.oneOf([Cell]) })
        ])
    }
`