# in Typescript, How to ensure React child components are of a certain type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I can't figure out how to make this work in Typescript. I've got a custom React component which should accept only a certain type of React components as children. I thought I could do something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
interface ChildProps {
  firstName?: string;
  lastName?: string;
}

interface ParentProps {
  children: Child[]
}

const Child = ({firstName, lastName}: ChildProps) => {return <div>child</div>}

const Parent = ({children}:ParentProps) => {
  return <div>{children}<div>
}

<Parent>
 <Child> {/* should work */}
 <Child> {/* should work */}
 <Child> {/* should work */}
 <div>this should throw error. Right?</div>
</Parent>
```

What I was hoping was that I could enforce that only `Child` components are handed to the parent, and I thought it was easy to do, but I'm a bit stumped. I've tried `children: Child[]`, and `children: JSX.Element<Child>[]`, and a few other things.

I found this SO question, but I can't quite make sense out of it:
[Typescript: how to set type of children in React Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36085104/typescript-how-to-set-type-of-children-in-react-component)

I'm sure it's something dumb I'm doing. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

You can't put a contraint on the type of children, but you can do selective rendering of the children (or throw an exception while running).

Take a look at this code:

```
private getCorrectChildren(): JSX.Element[] {
    const result: JSX.Element[] = [];
    React.Children.forEach(this.props.children, child => {
        if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
            if (child.type === MyTypeOfChildHere) {
                result.push(child);
            }
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

This method can be called in the `render()` method and will only return children of the right type. You can, of course, throw an error if the `child.type` is different than the one you are expecting.

PS. This is quite verbose and can optimized to be a smaller method, but this is easier to understand.

Comment: Hmm...actually wait. I did some digging, and found this: `interface ParentProps { children: React.ReactElement<ChildProps>[] }`. That appears to work, actually. It requires that the children are React elements, all with the prop shape of `ChildProps`. That's pretty close to what I want, if not exactly what I want.

Comment: @hairbo maybe you should answer the question with that, get some internet points